# How to pass along custom variable created in .gitlab-ci.yml to Docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Within `.gitlab-ci.yml` I've created a new variable under `script:` by using `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` and modifying it. When I `echo` the variable it returns the proper value. However, I'm not having any success passing it along to Docker. What am I not doing right?

Ultimately, I would like access this custom variable inside my container.

```
build:
  script:
    # converts commit SHA to UNIX time
    - export COMMIT_TIME_UNIX=$(git show -s --format=%ct $CI_COMMIT_SHA)
    - echo $COMMIT_TIME_UNIX
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check, when the same script is executed in a Docker/container environment, if it is still in the right Git repository path.

You can add, before the first export:

```
pwd
git status
env|grep GIT
```

That way, you will check if you are doing Git commands where you should, and if there is any `GIT_xxx` environnement variable which might influence said command.

Comment: pardon the delayed response as I'm in the middle of a move. Here's what I came up with and it seems to work. Added the `export` line from my code above to `before_script:` before any stage build. Then also before any stage build added `COMMIT_TIME_UNIX: $COMMIT_TIME_UNIX` to `variables:`.

Comment: @MixMasterMike I don't see in your comment the output of the commands I mentioned in my answer.